# Rotating Text in WPF TextBox without rotating control itself

Tags: c#, wpf

The question is: how could I rotate text inside WPF TextBox **without** rotating TextBox itself? **`(Rotate text only)`**
I have tried different RenderTransforms, LayoutTransforms but this did not help me.

Comment: rotate only text?

Comment: Yes, rotate text only

Comment: i dont think its possible

Comment: How one would know if only text is rotating or entire textbox is rotating?

Comment: He would if TextBox has a background color like in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer myself: put TextBox inside other control, i.e. in RIchTextBox:

```
  <RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
          <TextBlock Text="Stacked text!">
          <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
          </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
          </TextBlock>
        </Paragraph>
      </FlowDocument>
  </RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the correct solution to your question would be to define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `TextBox` and apply the `RotateTransform` to the `ScrollViewer` element:

```
<TextBox Background="Yellow" Text="test">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ScrollViewer.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
                    </ScrollViewer.LayoutTransform>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```